# SwiftUI hyperLink with UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, hyperlink, uiviewrepresentable

I am trying to create `HyperLink` with `UITextView` in `UIViewRepresentable` but I can't see any text in UITextView.

**Using:**

```
ArtieHyperLink(url: "https://www.google.com.tr", text: "This is HyperLink test.", hyperText: "test")
```

**UIViewRepresentable:**

```
struct ArtieHyperLink: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String = ""
    var text: String = ""
    var hyperText: String = ""
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = [.link]
        textView.textColor = .black
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let range = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: hyperText)
        let url = URL(string: url)!
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: range)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        
        var artieHyperLink: ArtieHyperLink
        
        init(_ artieHyperLink: ArtieHyperLink) {
            self.artieHyperLink = artieHyperLink
        }
        
        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes in the `UIViewRepresentable` implementation:

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
```

should be

```
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
```

Because `self` is a struct, i.e. value type, the `self` passed to the `Coordinator` will be out of date if the struct is init again because `makeCoordinator` is only called once. `View` and `ViewRepresentable` structs are re-init very frequently in SwiftUI because that's how its diffing algorithm works.

You must implement `updateUIView` and copy all of the properties of this struct that might have changed to the UITextView and/or the coordinator , e.g.

```
   func updateUIView(_ textView: UITextView, context: Context) {
         
        // use url, text and hyperText to update the textView, e.g.
         textView.attributedText = // update it if different

         etc...
    }
```

Here's a tip, it's simpler to have the coordinator make the UITextView in a lazy property, e.g.

```
 class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        lazy var textView: UITextView {
            let textView = UITextView()
            textView.delegate = self
            return textView
        }
```

Then you can simply do:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    return context.coordinator.textView
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I gave just width and height.. it's work. :)